# Errors trying to remove a range a cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a small code to remove a range of cells from 2 separate worksheets and Worksheets that are starting with letter N, but always my code is giving me errors or Excel is crashing. The first and second line of code with ClearContents method is giving me those errors.

[image: Error from the code execution]

My code:

```
'clearing ranges
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A4", range("AY4").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A3", range("AK3").End(xlDown)).ClearContents

'deleting sheets
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(sh.Name, 1) = "N" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sh.Name).Delete
    End If
Next sh
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a variable called `range` in your code?

Comment: no i don't have a variable called range

Comment: It's not clear what range you are trying to clear, but If you are trying to clear the rows 3 and 4, you can try `xlToRight` instead of `xlDown` or just `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("3:4").ClearContents`

Comment: i want to delete the range from  A4 until the right down corner of AY4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit** to add some code for the `ClearContents` issue

---

**ClearContents** issue

you wrote

> I want to delete the range from A4 until the right down corner of AY4

now it's up to what is to be intended as the *"right down corner of AY4"*

should it be the last non empty value on column AY then use:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet001")
    .Range("A4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AY").End(xlUp)).ClearContents
End With
```

you may need some more code to handle the case the first non empty cell in column "AY" is above row 4

---

**Sheet Deletion**

you may want to try the "Array" approach to exploit an array *flavour* of the `Item` property of `Worksheets` collection and have a one-shot sheets deletion:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ws()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim shtsToDelete As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each sh In .Worksheets
            If Left(sh.name, 1) = "N" Then shtsToDelete = shtsToDelete & sh.name & "\" '<-_| store sht names in a string delimiting them with an invalid character for sheet names
        Next sh
        If shtsToDelete <> "" Then '<--| if any sheet to be deleted has been found
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False '<--| disable alerts to prevent popping out of msgbox prompting you to confirm sheets deletion
            .Worksheets(Split(Left(shtsToDelete, Len(shtsToDelete) - 1), "\")).Delete '<--| delete list-sheets in one shot
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True '<--| enable alerts back
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: My code is crashing or not responding well from first two clearcontents methods of those ranges. Now i realised that my for each loop is not good practice, but is working fine

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because you are not allowed to delete objects inside of the current `for each` loop. Try using a `for` loop, like this:

```
For i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count to 1 Step -1
  If Left(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).name, 1) = "N" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Delete
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: Using a `For Each` loop to delete sheets works for me. Maybe different Excel versions?

Comment: I've often had an error when deleting the current 'for each' object, so I try to avoid deleting inside a for each loop, maybe worksheets are okay.

Comment: @TBiel unless you know exactly how the for each loop works with collections (which I don't) that's probably a good idea

Answer (score 0):

your Range definition is wrong, in the inner Range method call, you don't access the range of a specific sheet, so it uses Range of the default sheet. Second problem: If you delete something in a collection, you should loop backwards over the collection because otherwise the Delete operation leads index changes during the loop.

```
Dim wsheet1 As Worksheet
Dim wsheet2 As Worksheet

Set wsheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

wsheet1.Columns("A:AY").ClearContents
wsheet2.Columns("A:AK").ClearContents

For i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
  If Left(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name, 1) = "N" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Delete
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: Still crashes my excel file, I associated this code with a button. I ran the code without  for loop and also only  clearcontents for first sheet . After i press it Excel is not responding and I have to close the file and start again

Comment: strange, does it work if you create a new excel file just with this code? Did you set Application.ScreenUpdating = false somewhere in your vba code?

Comment: I simplified the code a bit (using columns instead of range)